# How to re-create this layout in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am re-writing my application from Kotlin to Flutter, but I need help with Flutter widgets.

I'm trying to re-create layout I did in Native Kotlin fro Android in Flutter, but I am struggling with simple things.

This is the original layout I did in Kotlin: 
[image: kotlin]

And this is the layout I almost did in Flutter:
[image: flutter]

I want the image to be stretched all the way from left to right like in Kotlin layout.

I also want the text "Wybierz kupon" to be at the center.

If only Flutter's Container widget had children, I could do this.

Is there anyone, who can help me?

The code in Flutter:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Coupon extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png'),
          Text('Wybierz Kupon'),
          FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          disabledColor: Colors.grey,
          disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            "Klasyczny kupon",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to discover extra widget:
check this: https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/widgets
and watch youtube series  [flutter widget of the week](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw/featured)

About your question: you can use the center widget here

[image]

```
class Coupon extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png'),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Wybierz Kupon',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              disabledColor: Colors.grey,
              disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                "Klasyczny kupon",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that solves the problem for "Wybierz kupon" text, but what about the image? How to I make it stretch all the way from left to right? I want the button to have margins on left and right, but not the image.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. i just need to add margin on a container that wraps FlatButton, but thanks for an answer!

Comment: @szakes1, do upvote the answer for his efforts. Everyone here is a great teacher, and a learner, and if someone is working out on your problem and gives you the right solution, please encourage it with upvotes and mark it as correct so that people in future would come and find this answer useful. You will also gain points for that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

the body can do like this

```
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Color(0xFF36474f),

          actions: <Widget>[
            // action button
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
               Text('Jak UZYWAC?',style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: whiteColour
                )),
             Text('HAMBURGER',style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: whiteColour
                )),
             Text('LODY',style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: whiteColour
                )),
             Text('CHEESEBURGER',style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: whiteColour
                )),   
            ],)

            // overflow menu
          ]         
  ),
            body:  Container(    color: Color(0xFF36474f),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png'),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Wybierz Kupon:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: whiteColour
                )),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.orange,            
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "Klasyczny kupon",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,            
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "Klasyczny kupon",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.white),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

And TabBar does based on this example:

```
class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   _tabController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          final String label = tab.text.toLowerCase();
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'This is the $label tab',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but you really didn't have to make Tabs, but thanks anyway!